# \bibliography changes \textheight

Tags: bibliographies, margins

I'm experiencing a strange behavior of the `\bibliography` command (BibTeX). I'm seeing that, after `\bibliography` is issued, the `\textheight` is changed, and the references go slightly beyond the end of the text at the bottom of the page.

I have my own document class, and the formatting for the bibliography is done with:

```
% Bibliography formatting
\RequirePackage{natbib}

\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\refname}}
\bibliographystyle{eage}
```

where `eage.bst` has been created answering to the questions received while running `latex makebst.tex`.

Into the LaTeX file, at the end of the document, I simply issue

```
\bibliography{BOOKS,additional}
```

and then I see references at the bottom of the right column (I have a two column article) going slightly beyond the bottom of the left column (and then they continue on the next page).

Comment: Do you actually mean that `\textheight` is changed? (what happens if you insert `\showthe\textheight` at various places, do you get different values shown? Or do you just mean that some text overran the bottom of the page (which could be for lots of reasons, not all of which involve `\textheight`) For example if any entries are being placed in unbreakable boxes this could happen. As usually the case, a full minimal working example would help.

Comment: The issues you're experiencing may be related more to the specific two-column page layout of your document class than to the `natbib` package, the redefined `\bibsection` macro, or the specific bibliography style file you've created with the `makebst` utility. (BibTeX definitely does not do any typesetting on its own.) Does your document class by any cnance modify the `\thebibliography` macro?

Comment: You are right. I have tried the same bst but with the standard article document class and the references are perfectly aligned with the column on the left. So the problem should be in my cls file. I have to figure out which is the command that breaks things.

Answer (score 1):

I've found where the problem was. In my `.cls` file, I was setting the `\textheight` to a value that was not an integer multiple of `\baselineskip`. For this reason, the column of text was never completely full (in fact, I was receiving `underfull vbox` warnings). On the other hand, the bibliography list was able to fill the text area slightly more, and the effect was what I described at the beginning.